# MongoDB OData .NET Driver With Support for Open Types

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

Is there a MongoDB v3.6 OData .NET C# driver that supports OData open types?

From Microsoft docs: "Open type is a structured type that contains dynamic properties, in addition to any properties that are declared in the type definition. Open types let you add flexibility to your data models. This tutorial shows how to use open types in ASP.NET Web API OData."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official MongoDB C# driver does support open types.
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/

Based on the MS tutorial (in the question) this is what the MongoDB data looks like. The data format concerns me especially if reporting directly off MongoDB is needed.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a5ba996376675486418de49"),
    "ISBN": "978-0-7356-7942-9",
    "Title": "Microsoft Azure SQL Database Step by Step",
    "Press": {
        "Name": "Microsoft Press",
        "Email": null,
        "Category": 2,
        "DynamicProperties": {
            "Blog": "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/",
            "Address": {
                "_t": "Address",
                "City": "Redmond",
                "Street": "One Microsoft Way"
            }
        }
    },
    "Properties": {
        "Published": {
            "_t": "System.DateTimeOffset",
            "_v": [
                NumberLong(635399424000000000),
                0
            ]
        },
        "Authors": {
            "_t": "System.String[]",
            "_v": [
                "Leonard G. Lobel",
                "Eric D. Boyd"
            ]
        },
        "OtherCategories": {
            "_t": "ODataAndMongoTrial2.Category[], ODataAndMongoTrial2",
            "_v": [
                0,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
}
```